# Validate and save address using AJAX in WooCommerce

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Using WordPress 4.6.1 and WooCommerce 2.6.4

I need to create an multi-step checkout for `WooCommerce`, where customer first fill his address, then he click on "Next" where we validate and save his address.

Before that, the customer proceed the next steps to checkout.

I did fine all the changes, customizing the WooCommerce templates, but I struggle with the "Next" button action.
How can I create the functionality of validate and save the address form using AJAX? I want pretty much the "edit-address" endpoint functionality, but using AJAX.

I check `class-wc-ajax.php` to see how can I save the address form using ajax, but there is nothing that could help me.
The close I got was the `process_checkout()` function on `class-wc-ajax.php`, but it does the "final" checkout and I need to put more steps on the checkout process.

I don't want to rewrite all the login of validating and saving this, since WC already do it.
There is at least a function of WC that help me to validate and save easily?

How can I do what I need? Any tips/help?

Thank you guys!

Comment: I'm using WooCommerce for this. Sorry, it wasn't clear on my question. I change the WooCommerce templates for create the checkout I want, but still using the core functions. What I need is to know if there is a function/hook in WooCommerce core that easily validate and save the address form, so I could create an endpoint to use AJAX.

Comment: I just found the function `save_address()` in file `class-wc-form-handler.php` that possibly can help me. Anyone knows better about it?